# Using SCSS variables and themes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

What's the best practice for implementing themes and SCSS variables in an Angular project?

For example, I don't want to have to write 'color: blue' everywhere in my app. I'd rather write 'color: $primary' and have a variable in the global styles sheet called $primary that I can set to blue.

```
// Global Variables

$primary: #00204a;
$secondary: #00bbf0;
$accent: #fdb44b;
$warn: red;
$success: green;
```

Just putting those variables there in styles.scss doesn't make them accessible in my component's style sheets. Do I have to import anything?

What approach should I use for themes in Angular? Everything I am reading regarding themes seems to be for Angular Material, wouldn't we want to create a theme for the whole site and not just Angular Material components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `:root` in your `styles.scss`:

```scss
:root {
  --primary: #00204a;
  --secondary: #00bbf0;
  --accent: #fdb44b;
  --warn: red;
  --success: green;
}
```

Then it will be possible to use these variables anywhere in your app:

```scss
.button {
  background-color: var(--primary);
}
```